# Windows WCF Service using HTTPS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, service, app-config

I have a working WCF service that I am trying to add SSL security too. I followed tutorials for creating the dev certificates and I think i got all that set up; however, when I install and try to start my service, its failing without an error. I am using the installutil [servicename.exe] and the service gets installed. Then I try to start the service and it wont start. The only changes I made in the previously working app config are below:

I added Transport Security via the following:

```
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
</security>
```

I changed the base address from `"http://localhost/service" to "https://localhost/service"`

and I added a service behavior to allow httpsGets via the following:

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

I wish I had more details on the error but basically it just says the windows service cannot be started, and that makes it really hard to troubleshoot. Any advice or tips would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you change the security Mode to "None" does the service start?

Comment: No, changing it to None still does not work

Comment: Does changing the prefix back to http from https help? The idea here is to narrow down what's causing the service not to start. If it's indeed the actual WCF service code, or something else. Do you have any logging in place? Have you checked the application logs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: I have toggled all of the configuration options on and off to try to narrow it down. Basically, if ANY of them are turned on, it doesn't start. I don't currently have any logging in place as the service was just recently built; however, the service does work without any issues when those three options are turned off.

Comment: under bindings in the appconfig, it is set up to use basicHttpBindings if that is important..?

Comment: if you remove the <security mode="Transport" /> (entire line) and set the address to http:// instead of https:// it should work. Without seeing an error, there isn't much more we can do to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Check windows error log with eventvwr. You may find exception details there. Do you have any logging configured?